# Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags:

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search, ignored-tags

I added ignored tags, so my timeline is not filled with them. In my timeline I want to only see questions I can answer.

I'm trying to search for a specific tag and related questions to learn about it. But it seems I've ignored so many tags that nothing out of 6K questions shows up.

I frequently find myself using an incognito browser to easily escape this, but there I run into captcha which is even more annoying.

What should I do to fix this?

1. Edit my tags
2. Enter a specific variable to hide `ignored tags` for this search?
3. ???

What can SO do to fix this?

1. Add a button to hide `ignored tags` for this search?
2. ???

[image]

Comment: There is another alternative - you can set the ignored tags to *show* but be greyed out. https://i.imgur.com/0rjVmlT.png

Comment: Alternatively, search for `is:q [passport.js]`.

Comment: Set it to 50 results per page, probably some results will then popup :)

Comment: I see the "more" filter is selected- are you using a custom filter, rather than a direct search? It's possible the filter could be doing something funky.

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm just sorting by votes, nothing fancy